# How to remove a specific term page link?

Tags: views, 8, taxonomy-terms

I have taxonomy term list page..

- Apple
- Banana
- Sweets
- Cake

These are the terms listed with links to default term page.

suppose I want to remove the link for Apple only but listed how do I go about it?

I have tried this

```
  function mytheme_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
    if (isset($node->content['field_fruit_name'])) {
      foreach ($node->content['field_fruit_name']['#items'] as $delta => $item) {
         if (count(taxonomy_select_nodes($item['taxonomy_term']->tid)) < 2) {
           $title = $node->content['field_fruit_name'][$delta]['#title'];
           $node->content['field_fruit_name'][$delta] = array();
           $node->content['field_fruit_name'][$delta]['#markup'] = $title;
         }
      }
    }
  }
```

its not working... so if i can remove the link for each term individually it would be great.

Comment: Term list page created by views?

Comment: I mean to say Taxonomy terms Listed on a page using views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Little bit tricky but you can achieve without code.

1. Add a new boolean field to taxonomy term.(eg: show link(field name))

[image]

Save for each term show link value either true or false. Depend you wants to show the link or hide the link for that term.

2. Add three fields like shown in the image in your views.

[image]

3. Taxonomy term: Name [hidden] -- **Exclude from display** and deselect link to taxonomy term

[image]

4. Taxonomy term: Term ID [hidden]  -- **Exclude from display**

[image]

5. Taxonomy term: show link

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: did it as you said --- checking the the box on/off does nothing... the links are still there.

Comment: you can see the answer and let me know anything not clear.

Comment: let me try -- ill let you know

Comment: thank you for the help --- unfortunately I haven't been able to implement it... is there away to implement with code.